# Deixar Iframe Responsivo, sem envolvê-lo em nunhum elemento

Tags: iframe, layout-responsivo

Galera é o seguinte, estou precisando deixar um iframe responsivo.
 Só que para complicar não tenho como fazer deixar esse iframe envolto em outro elemento.
Ex:

```
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Meu Titulo</h1>
    <p>Meu artigo</p>
      <iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/bla"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Preciso deixar isso responsivo, sem elementos para envolver o iframe.
Nem sei se isso é possível, mas se for seria de grande ajuda, se você puder me ajudar com isso.

Answer (score 2):

Tecnicamente responsivo é controlado pelos *media-queries*, com variações dependendo da situação, mas no seu caso um `width: 100%;` deve resolver:

```css
.content iframe {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<h1>Meu Titulo</h1>
<p>Meu artigo</p>
<iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/bla"></iframe>
</div>
```

Se você limitar do `.content` a largura irá ficar assim:

```css
.content {
    width: 300px;
}

.content iframe {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<h1>Meu Titulo</h1>
<p>Meu artigo</p>
<iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/bla"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, isso ajuda.